# Upscaling and deblocking a video

Tags: virtualdub, adobe-after-effects

I have a small collection of old 360p/480p videos that I am considering upscaling since they no longer look good on my 1440p monitor. I tried After Effects 'Detail-preserve upscale' plug-in and some color and level correction and while the upscale was really really good, the blocking due to low res also got amplified. Now adobe doesn't has a built-in plugin for deblocking but I know that 'VirtualDub MSU Smart Deblocking Filter' is in a class of its own. I processed my 2K upscaled video through the filter and it produced extremely amazing results.
My query is would you suggest deblocking the video before or after upscaling?
I chose to deblock after upscaling cause I assume that since the block size is also upscaled, the deblocking filter will be better able to process it or is going the other way a better choice?

Answer (score 0):

Since no one would help, I decided to do my own tests.
Deblocking prior to upscaling results in a better quality output. My best guess is that the 'detail-preserve upscale' plug-in adds sharpness to the video which enhances the blocking artifacts making it difficult for the deblocking filter to process.
Plus, it is easier on the resources to process a lower resolution video for deblocking than an upscaled video and therefore faster as well.